# Kernel task memory is not released in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, memory, kernel, osx-yosemite

I was working on a large Illustrator project in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) which takes up 4.5GB+ memory but after I save and quit the application, my kernel task has still 4.8GB in it and not being released. Why?

[image]